# PostgreSQL not working with virtual envirement

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, virtualenv, psycopg2

I want to use psycopg2 (PostgreSQL) with virtualenv.

I am using Ubuntu and root already having psycopg2 and it is working fine but if i try to use it after activating virtualenv it shows

`ImportError: No module named psycopg2`

Do i need to put symbolic link of dist-packages manually ??

Comment: You have to install psycopg2 when your virtualenv is activated. What is the output of `pip freeze -l` in your virtualenv?

Comment: No i haven't installed psycopg2 when virtualenv is activated. And i don't want to use because i root already having it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

virtualenvs are by default isolated from the system packages so you need to install all packages into each virtualenv (or you can pass `--system-site-packages` when creating it).